# React Native Calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, calendar, react-native-calendars

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";

import { Calendar } from "react-native-calendars";

const Home = () => {
    const [date, setDate] = useState("")
    const [datecolor,setDateColor]=useState("")

    const addZero = (a) => {
        if (a < 10 && a > 0) {
            return '0' + a.toString();
        } else {
            return a;
        }
    }
    const getCurrentDate = () => {
        var date = new Date().getDate();
        var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
        var year = new Date().getFullYear();
        return year + '-' + addZero(month) + '-' + addZero(date);//yyyy-mm-dd
    }

    const getMinDate = () => {
        var date = new Date().getDate();
        var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
        var year = new Date().getFullYear();
        return year + '-' + addZero(month) + '-' + addZero(date);//yyyy-mm-dd
    }
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View>
                <Calendar
                    current={getCurrentDate().toString()}
                    minDate={getMinDate().toString()}
                    maxData={'2050-01-01'}
                    monthFormat={'MMMM yyyy'}
                    onDayPress={day => {
                        setDate(day.dateString)
                        setDateColor("#000")
                    }}
                    hideArrows={false}
                    hideExtraDays={true}
                    disableMonthChange={false}
                    firstDay={1}
                    theme={{
                        todayTextColor: 'red',
                    }}
                />
                <Text style={{fontSize:20,textAlign:'center',fontSize:25,fontWeight:'bold'}}>{date}</Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

### Below is my code

- it's running in perfect
- but I want if I select any date in the calendar date background color change
- like By default select a date in the calendar

  #### **How I can do**

This is my output

[image]

here I select 20 date but 20 date background not change in calendar

I want Like 12 date background in calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add props called `markedDates` to `Calendar` component. You can see the example in the docs here [wix/react-native-calendars](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars)

```js
...
      <Calendar
        markedDates={{
          [date]: { selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue' },
        }}
        current={getCurrentDate().toString()}
        minDate={getMinDate().toString()}
        maxData={'2050-01-01'}
        monthFormat={'MMMM yyyy'}
        onDayPress={(day) => {
          setDate(day.dateString);
          setDateColor('#000');
        }}
        hideArrows={false}
        hideExtraDays={true}
        disableMonthChange={false}
        firstDay={1}
        theme={{
          todayTextColor: 'red',
        }}
      />
...
```